# How can I eager load a relationship directly to the parent with its own keys without loop?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is there a direct way to eager load the relationships key values directly into the parent. I mean without storing it under a sub element?

for example:

```
$user = User::with('contact');
```

but instead returning this:

```
[
    'name'=>'john',
    'surname'=>'doe'
    'contact' => [
        'phone' => '...',
        'email' => '...@...'
    ]
]
```

I want directly this:

```
[
    'name'=>'george',
    'surname'=>'doe',
    'phone' => '...',
    'email' => '...@...'
]
```

I could loop all users and place that value manually but I am wondering if there is a way that directly calls these from database. It would save me a lot of resource if there would be a direct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the relationship of `User` and `Contact` is `One-To-One` you can run such a query:

```
User::join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
    ->select(['name', 'username', 'phone', 'email'])
    ->get();
```